# Check if props is present with ternary operator

Tags: reactjs

I have a conditional statement where I'm checking if the path includes hello and buy in them then return null. (Path is getting passed to the component as props). But if path isn't getting passed I don't want the page to break. How do I write a conditional here to check if the path is available? This is what I wrote

```
if  path ? ((path.includes('/hello') || (path.includes('/bye')) : '') {
        return null
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of checking if the `path` prop is `undefined`, you can give it a default value of an empty string and keep your code as it is.

```
function MyComponent({ path = '' }) {
  if (path.includes('/hello') || path.includes('/bye')) {
    return null;
  }

  // ...
}
```